# How to show $f(A)$ is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If $A$ is diagonalizable and $f(·)$ is a polynomial, how to show that $f(A)$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: So what is $A$?  Any infinite dimensional Hermitian matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$A=SDS^{-1} \implies A^2=SDS^{-1}SDS^{-1}=SD^2S^{-1} \implies \dots A^n=SD^nS^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks ! this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to show (based on gimusi's hint) that if $A= BDB^{-1}$, then

$$f(A)= Bf(D)B^{-1}$$ as well..

and a polynomial applied to the subgroup of diagonal matrices stays in there.